# Cannot find module folder

Tags: 8

I installed [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) 8.x-1.0-alpha2 using `/admin/modules/install` and then pasting the url to the tar file.

Now I want to uninstall/delete it, but I cannot find where the folder is.

I have checked in `/modules` and `/core/modules`

I even tried uploading the dev version to the `/modules` folder, but it does not ask me to overwrite.

This is so strange, where else could it be?

#### Update

I tried as [suggested by sanzante](http://comment-267099) using Devel and `echo drupal_get_path('module', 'simplenews')`

it says `modules/simplenews`

[image]

but when I try to go there with FileZilla, it does not let me. I also re-started FileZilla multiple times.

[image]

Comment: If you have shell access you can locate it using find executable: `find /path/drupal/root -type d -name simplenews`

Comment: @sanzante sadly I do not

Comment: Maybe in `sites/all/modules`?

Comment: @mradcliffe there is no `sites/all` folder in D8.

Comment: I should had known, sorry. Then try to execute this code (for example, using a devel PHP window): `drupal_get_path('module', 'simplenews')` and print result or write it to a log file.

Comment: I bet is something related to the FTP server, it may not see the changes on the dir. To move forward in the PHP approach you can check the dir contents using PHP: ` scandir(path/to/modules/dir);`

Comment: File permissions?

Comment: @Kevin the modules folder was/is [set to 755](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTESG.jpg)

Comment: @sanzante `echo scandir('/drupal/modules/simplenews');` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @NoSssweat check the log file, scandir write its errors there.

Comment: @sanzante `print_r(scandir('modules/simplenews'));` worked, it lists all the files.

Comment: @NoSssweat : I hesitate to post this as an actual answer (I might if I'm close ...), but there is something not quite right in what shows in the right panes of your FileZilla screenprint: to the right of **remote site:** I see something that ends with "modules/simplenews", so that should display the content (below it) of what's in the simplenews directory. However, it displays a whole list of modules (eg views_field_view, token, etc). Could it be that somehow **all** your modules are copied (or moved?) within that "modules/simplenews" directory? And because of that "strange things happen"?

Comment: @NoSssweat it seems that the FTP servers is unable to get the actual file listing of the modules dir so it denies access to simplenews module. Double check file permissions (simplenews was installed using Drupal so it may have different permissions or owner than the rest of modules) and try to restart FTP server.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens no, as you can see in the top left, I am trying to access that folder. The folders that you there is actually the `/modules` folder. As you can [see here it is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gehmj.jpg). The remote site box is to access stuff directly (kind like a url bar of a web browser)

Comment: ok, good enough. Then I bet (also?) it is some file permission issue, whereas at least your Filezilla userid "pttv" (shown upper left in Filezilla screenprint) does not have read access to the SimpleNews module dir. And if you can't see it, you can'"t delete it, right? Time to get some root-user involved to go check the owner, group, etc of the simpleNews dir?

Comment: FYI @NoSssweat You've only blanked some of the domain references in that image...

Comment: @Clive good eyes, thx.

Comment: @NoSssweat, no, Drupal 8 still supports modules in `sites/all/**` per [ExtensionDiscovery::scan](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Extension!ExtensionDiscovery.php/function/ExtensionDiscovery%3A%3Ascan/8.2.x). It was a possibility since the question did not have many details about the site install when I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that his site was moved to another server.

The FTP that I was seeing was from the old server. When I installed the simplenews it got installed in the new server.

Comment: Too bad this question was not asked on an April 1st ... !!!